# Timer in angular ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, timer

Currently working on a puzzle app in angular where time(in mins format) is provided in the json for each set, my requirement is that I will have to run a counter for that mins and then close the set.

**json format provided is :**

```
[
    {
        "setId": 1,
        "setName": "Set-A",
        "totalQuestions": 20,
        "markPerQuestion": 1,
        "totalDuration": 10  ///time in minutes
    }
]
```

And I will have to show the timer in **hh:mm** format,so i have converted the 10 mins into **hh:mm** format but not able to get how i will run the counter to decrease the minutes and hour.

```
**Function for converting 10 into hh:mm format:**
 private time=10;
     showTime() {
        this.m = time % 60;
        this.h = (time - this.m) / 60;
        this.HRSMINS = this.h.toString() + ":" + (this.m < 10 ? "0" : "") + this.m.toString();
        console.log("Timer: "+this.HRSMINS);

      }
```